# Where am I going wrong? SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

```
$foot = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) 
                       FROM tblQA 
                      WHERE intResponseID = '' 
                        AND cCategory = 'Football' as qcount, 
                    (SELECT max(dPostDateTime) 
                       FROM tblQA 
                      WHERE intResponseID = '' 
                        AND cCategory = 'Football') as lastq");


$football = mysql_fetch_array($foot);

echo "<td class='forum'>" . $footbll['qcount'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='forum'>" . $footbll['lastq'] . "</td>";
```

This doesn't display anything in my table. I didn't post the entire HTML code, i have the table structure fine.

Comment: `$football` or `$footbll`, which is the correct spelling? Are you sure your query isn't generating any errors?

Comment: Impossible to tell. Copy+paste the complete query, run it in your database GUI and see whether any results come up.

Comment: Spelling was my mistake here, its correct in the code ($football)

Comment: @ Pekka, results come up fine in my db GUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is my solution. I figured it out:

```
$foot = mysql_query("SELECT count(*), max(dPostDateTime) FROM tblQA WHERE intResponseID = '' AND cCategory = 'Football'");

$football = mysql_fetch_assoc($foot);


echo "<td class='forum'><center>" . $football['count(*)'] . "</center></td>";
echo "<td class='forum'><center>" . $football['max(dPostDateTime)'] . "</center></td>";
```

Comment: This is exactly what OMG Ponies answer said to do (though his is still better than this one because of the column aliases). You should just accept his answer rather than create your own, mostly duplicate, answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
$foot = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS qcount,
                            MAX(dPostDateTime) AS lastq
                      FROM tblQA 
                     WHERE intResponseID = '' 
                       AND cCategory = 'Football' ");

$football = mysql_fetch_array($foot);

echo "<td class='forum'>" . $football['qcount'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='forum'>" . $football['lastq'] . "</td>";
```

I re-wrote your query, it could all be done within a single statement.

Answer (score 1):

If this is your literal code, you have a typo in `$footbll`.

Answer (score 0):

You should have something like:

```
while ($football = mysql_fetch_array($foot)) {
    echo "<td class='forum'>" . $football['qcount'] . "</td>";
    /* yadda yadda yadda */
}
```

You also had a few typos in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a combinator where the `,` sits: `...qcount, (SELECT...`

Answer (score 0):

The query doesn't make any sense, I am extremely surprised it returns something in your DB GUI.

If you didn't want to change the syntax, you would have to do something like this :

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblQA) AS qcount, (SELECT MAX(dPOstDateTime) FROM tblQA) AS lastq -- i didn't add the conditions
```

But it can be easily done by doing this query instead :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS qcount,
       MAX(dPostDateTime) AS lastq
FROM tblQA
WHERE intResponseID = ''
    AND cCategory = 'Football'
```

Please note also intResponseID sounds like it is an integer, it seems weird you are comparing it to an empty string...